# From terminal how can I upgrade a particular software only

Tags: apt, upgrade

Using Xubunutu 140.04 LTS I want to upgrade a particular software only without upgrading the rest of the system. How can this be done from terminal,

To update entire system I understand that I need to following

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get upgrade or dist-upgrade
```

but what if I want only a particular package and related dependencies to upgrade in my case I want to upgrade Firefox and is dependencies ? Is upgrading a particular software like this likely to break other packages which use the shared dependencies ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install firefox` should do the trick. You can check the linked post in muru's comment for more details.